# How do I grep in the content of a string variable?

Tags: grep

How to do a grep in a variable? I have stored the wget output in a variable and I need to extract out some strings from it.
Like the content of the variable is

```
upgrade http://wordpress.org/download/ http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.0.5.zip 3.0.5 en_US 4.3 4.1.2
```

I need to check if the string contains the word `upgrade`, so I can do a simple grep and then check the exit status of it by `$?` and proceed.

How can I get the value `3.0.5` which is actually the fourth word?

And how to actually grep in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking for a word you can use a for loop.

```
STRING="upgrade this if you can"
for x in $STRING; do
   echo $x
   if [ "$x" = 'upgrade' ]; then
       echo found
       y=$x
       break
   fi
done 
echo $y
```

If upgrade is always in the same position you could try array assignment.

```
declare -a z
z=($STRING)
echo ${z[0]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Although this fits the current question pretty well but Oli's answer is more detailed in case its not as easy as to grab words from a string

Answer (score 8):

Rather than grepping, perhaps just use `cut`. It'll be a lot faster than running a full regex.

```
STRING="upgrade http://wordpress.org/download/ http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.0.5.zip 3.0.5 en_US 4.3 4.1.2"
echo "$STRING" | cut -d" " -f4
```

Outputs: `3.0.5`

This might be a little more robust though (is grabs the version from the zip url):

```
echo "$STRING" | sed -n -e 's/.*wordpress-\(.*\)\.zip.*/\1/p'
```

If you want to store it back in a bash variable, just wrap that in quotes and backticks. The backticked part will execute first, leaving it as as string.

```
RESULT="`echo "$STRING" | sed -n -e 's/.*wordpress-\(.*\)\.zip.*/\1/p'`"
```

So as far as stripting this (per your comment) to look for `upgrade` at the beginning:

```
STRING="upgrade http://wordpress.org/download/ http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.0.5.zip 3.0.5 en_US 4.3 4.1.2"

if [[ $STRING == upgrade* ]]; then
    VERSION="`echo "$STRING" | sed -n -e 's/.*wordpress-\(.*\)\.zip.*/\1/p'`"
    # do something else now
else
    # do something if this isn't an upgrade (optional)
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the overall question you should be aware, that you can also use `grep` if the string contains several lines and you want to find out the line that contains a certain word.

Example:

```
STRING="Some lines
with the word one
and the word two"
```

use grep to find the line with the word "one" use echo with the variable quoted:

```
echo "$STRING" | grep one
```